# How to show that the closed unit ball is a measurable set for outer measure $m^*$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> How to show that $\{x \in \mathbb R^{n} : \|x\| \le 1 \}$ is an $m^* $-measurable set?

I know that a set $E$ is said to be $m^*$-measurable (or Lebesgue measurable) if for any set $A \subset \Bbb R^{n}$ we have,

$$m^*(A)=m^*(A \cap E)+m^*(A \cap E^C)$$

How should I use this definition? Is there any other method to show this?

Comment: Isn't this set closed? Closed sets are measurable.

Comment: Yes, in fact this is a closed $n$-dimensional unit ball. Okay so as per you say, I should first prove that any closed set is measurable.

Comment: Or read how to prove it for open sets, because you can just take the complement.

Comment: Okay that also seems nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $m^*$ is subadditive, the only thing that needs a proof is the inequality $$ m^*(A)\ge  m^*(A \cap E)+m^*(A \cap E^c)$$ Here is one approach.

1. Prove that $m^*$ is a *metric outer measure*, meaning that $m^*(A\cap B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ when $\operatorname{dist}(A,B)>0$. This follows from the fact that $m^*$ can be computed by taking covers by sufficiently small cubes, which do not intersect both $A$ and $B$ at the same time. Hence, any cover of $A\cup B$ can be separated into a cover of $A$ and a cover of $B$, which leads to $m^*(A\cap B)\ge  m^*(A)+m^*(B)$.
2. For an integer $k$, consider $A_k = \{x\in A:\operatorname{dist}(x,E)\ge 1/k\}$. Since $\operatorname{dist}(A\cap E, A_k)>0$, it follows that 
   $$
   m^*(A) \ge 
   m^*((A\cap E)\cup A_k) = m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A_k)$$
   It remains to note that $m^*(A_k)\to m^*(A\cap E^c)$ as $k\to\infty$, because $A\cap E^c$ is the union of the nested sequence $A_k$. (This latter fact relies on the assumption that $E$ is closed.)